# Hi Guys,I have recently started using ROC (catkin) I am unable to locate package ros-hydro-ros-tutorials. Please help me out

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I entered the following command as provided  in http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-ros-tutorials

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-groovy-ros-tutorials
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205178/hi-guys,i-have-recently-started-using-roc-(catkin)-i-am-unable-to-locate-package-ros-hydro-ros-tutorials.-please-help-me-out./) by [Spartan_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21890/spartan_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-03-17**:
What do you get for `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

What version of ROS are you using? Is it Groovy or Hydro? In ros--ros-tutorials, '' should be the ros version which you installed.
Were you successfully able to install ROS?

Naman

---

Originally posted by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) with karma: 1464 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0